# How do I fix my onclick event? It does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have this code that is not working I cant seem to error in this, any advice?

```
<div onclick=
    "document.getElementByID('newmessage').style.display='block'"
    class="inboxcon-white">
```

when click on that div, nothing happens `newmessage` is a div id from other div

Comment: It's hard to diagnose your problem without more information. Can you provide code samples?

Comment: Hi Ralph, you have to indent your html code otherwise we won't be able to see it in the question body.

Comment: `getElementByID` !== `getElementById`, basic typo.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, Godbless, It's finally working